Probability apple is delicious given a red apple is produced in a green apple orchard?
An example scenario of what I am trying to model:
A farmer has a large apple farm, producing green apples (C=baseline apple color ?). Sometimes, a red one is produced (B=apple is red). I am wondering whether the red apple is delicious, which is a binary variable (A = delicious or not delicious).
What is the best way to express this in bayesian probabilities? I initially thought (A|B,C). However, here the extended Bayes' theorem (for binary variable A), leads me to the expression:
$P(A | B,C) = \frac{P(B|A,C) P(A,|C) }{ P(C|B,A) P(A,C) + P(B|C not A) P(not A|C) }$
However, here P(A,|C) is meaningless, as A does not depend on C.
The Q is worded this way because now I am thinking that P(A | (B|C)) might be more correct, but I am not sure whether that is the case, or how to expand that.
The Q I really care about, is what is the probability of the apple being delicious, given B deviated from C. I want to be able to apply this to other orchards with other C's (baseline colors) and B's (unique color popping up).

The entire orchard is normally to produce geen apples, why bring in C ?

@trueblueanil other orchards produce other kinds of apples. I want to be able to apply this to all orchards, which may have different C's. You're right this seems to be key -- will edit to include to the post thanks!

Using conditional probability:
Given two events $~E_1~$ and $~E_2,~$
you have that
$$p(E_1) \times p(E_2 ~| ~E_1) = p(E_1,E_2) \implies 
p(E_2 ~| ~E_1) = \frac{p(E_1,E_2)}{p(E_1)}. \tag1 $$
Let

$E_1~$ denote the event that the apple is red.

$E_2~$ denote the event that the apple is delicious.


Then, you are trying to compute $~p(E_2 ~| ~E_1).$
Using the RHS of (1) above, in order to obtain an exact numerical answer, you need two preliminary computations:

$p(E_1,E_2).$

$p(E_1).$


Note that
$$p(E_1) = p(E_1,E_2) + p[ ~E_1, ~(\neg E_2) ~].$$
Edit
It can be argued that because of the above analysis, the probability that the apple is green is irrelevant, as is the percentage of green apples that are delicious, rather than not delicious.
The argument in the previous paragraph is (perhaps) misleading.  That is, if you have no direct way of computing $~p(E_1,E_2),~$ and $~p(E_1) = p(E_1,E_2) + p[ ~E_1, ~(\neg E_2) ~],~$ then it is plausible that a corresponding math problem could be constructed, where the information in the previous paragraph could assist you in computing the expressions in this paragraph.
For example:
$$p(\text{apple is green}) = p(\neg E_1) = 1 - p(E_1).$$

thanks! How do you incorporate the fact that the orchard produces green apples thourgh? as in, how is E1 is dependent on the original orchard colour?

@learning_physics You don't, unless (for example) you need to use $~p(\neg E_1)~$ to compute $~p(E_1).~$
